# I can’t run the NXT 1.0 program software on my Mac version 10.6

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, programming

How do I fix this? I run the install program, restart my computer, go to the “Applications” folder and there is a folder named “LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT”. I open the folder and there are three “options”: a folder named “engine”, a ".ini" file, and a “uninstall” file. I’ve browsed the “engine” folder and it’s full of ".ini” files. The “uninstall” file is a text file.

I don’t have any idea of what to do next. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Mindstroms NXT 2.0 software from [here](http://service.lego.com/en-us/helptopics/products/themes/mindstorms/mindstorms-nxt/nxt-software-download). It will run on newer versions of OS X.